# Integral $\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan(x))}+\frac{1}{1-\tan(x)}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am wondering if anyone would know how to evaluate this integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan(x))}+\frac{1}{1-\tan(x)}\right)dx.$$

I've tried, unsuccessfully, the change of variables $u=\tan (x)$.

Comment: For the second half use,  $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$

Comment: That's what I did too, @labbhattacharjee. What would you recommend for the first term in the integrand? I tried the same mapping, $x \mapsto \frac{\pi}{4} - x$, but I ended up with $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{1}{\log(1-\tan x) - \log(1+\tan x)}$$.

Comment: Khallil, you can write the difference of logs as a log of a quotient, and then apply the tangent angle sum identity.

Comment: Do you know the source for this integral?

Comment: @Khalil the difference to both is of the order $10^6$, you're wrong, see (this page on wolfram alpha) **
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B4%7D%7D+(+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Clog+(%5Ctan+x)%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1-%5Ctan+x%7D+)dx+-+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D+%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B4%7D%7D+(+%5Ccot+x+%2B+1+)+dx)**

Comment: @ThomasAndrews most probably, **not surely** , the OP maybe possible, wanted to um maybe put the upper limit as $\pi/2$

Comment: WolframAlpha doesn't give a closed-form solution for the integrand over the interval given, and it is usually sufficiently clever to do so, which supports your guess, @Aditya.

Comment: @Aditya: I am afraid that the OP is genuinely interested in the $\dfrac\pi4$ case, inasmuch as, if we were to substitute $u=\tan x$, the integral would become $\displaystyle\int_0^1\bigg(\dfrac1{\ln x}+\dfrac1{1-x}\bigg)\dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}$, which looks awfully similar to $\displaystyle\int_0^1\bigg(\dfrac1{\ln x}+\dfrac1{1-x}\bigg)~dx=\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Our saviour, @Lucian!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have the following closed form evaluation.

> $$
> I:=\int_0^{\Large \frac{\pi}{4}}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{\ln(\tan x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan x}\right)\! \mathrm dx= \color{blue}{\frac\pi8+\frac74\ln2+\frac\gamma2+\ln\pi-2\ln \Gamma\!\left(\!\frac14\!\right)} \tag1
> $$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

A numerical approximation is
$$
I =\color{blue}{0.462999316582640135993449151416572....}
$$

As Lucian pointed out, by the change of variable $\displaystyle u=\tan x$, we readily have
$$
I=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\frac{1}{1+u^2} \mathrm du.
$$
We set
$$
I(s):=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\frac{u^s}{1+u^2} \mathrm du, \quad s>-1.
$$
The expected integral is thus $I(0)$.

Let's differentiate $I(s)$.

We get 
$$
\begin{align}
I'(s)& =\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\frac{u^s\ln u}{1+u^2} \mathrm du \\\\
& =\int_0^1\left(1+\frac{\ln u}{1-u}\right)\frac{u^s}{1+u^2} \mathrm du \\\\
& =\int_0^1\! \frac{u^s}{1+u^2}\mathrm du +\int_0^1\!\frac{(1+u)u^s \ln u}{(1-u^2)(1+u^2)}\mathrm du \\\\
& =\int_0^1\! \frac{u^s(1-u^2)}{1-u^4}\mathrm du +\int_0^1\!\frac{u^s \ln u}{1-u^4}\mathrm du+\int_0^1\!\frac{u^{s+1} \ln u}{1-u^4}\mathrm du.
\end{align}
$$
By the change of variable $\displaystyle v=u^4$ in each of the preceding integrals and recalling the well known integral representations for the digamma function $\displaystyle \psi : = \Gamma'/\Gamma$ and for its derivative,
$$
\psi(s) = -\gamma+\int_0^1 \frac{1 - v^{s-1}}{1 -v}{\rm{d}} v, \quad s>0,
$$
$$
\psi'(s) = -\int_0^1 \frac{s^{s-1} \ln v}{1 - v}{\rm{d}} v, \quad s>0,
$$
we obtain

> $$
> I'(s)=\frac{1}{4}\psi\left(\frac{s+3}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\psi\left(\frac{s+1}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{16}\psi'\left(\frac{s+2}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{16}\psi'\left(\frac{s+1}{4}\right). \tag2
> $$

Since $$ \left|\left(\frac{1}{\ln u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\frac{u^s}{1+u^2} \right| < u^s, \quad 0<u<1,\, s>-1,$$ 
giving
$$ |I(s)|\leq \int_0^1\left|\left(\frac{1}{\ln u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\frac{u^s}{1+u^2} \right|\mathrm du < \!\!\int_0^1 u^s\mathrm du = \frac{1}{s+1}, $$ 
then, as $s \rightarrow +\infty$, we have $I(s) \rightarrow 0$.

We deduce that

> $$
> I(s)=\log \Gamma \left(\frac{s+3}{4}\right)\!-\!\log \Gamma \left(\frac{s+1}{4}\right) \!-\!\frac{1}{4}\psi\!\left(\frac{s+2}{4}\right)\!-\!\frac{1}{4}\psi\!\left(\frac{s+1}{4}\right)
> , \, s>-1, \tag3
> $$

and, for $s=0$,

> $$
> \begin{align}
> I=\frac\pi8+\frac74\ln2+\frac\gamma2+\ln\pi-2\ln \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)
> \end{align}
> $$

where have used [special values of the digamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.4(ii)),
$$
\begin{align}
\psi \left(\frac12\right) & = -\gamma - 2\ln 2, \\
\psi \left(\frac14\right) & =  -\gamma + \frac\pi2- 3\ln 2,
\end{align}
$$
and the [complement/reflection formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5)
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac\pi4)}=\pi \sqrt{2}.
$$

Comment: Can one safely say, then, that this cannot integrate to an elementary function?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**Noti ce that this is not an answer with same limits as question, but I'm leaving it here for others to help them if the upper limit was changed.**

---

We have the following integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan(x))}+\frac{1}{1-\tan(x)}\right)dx\tag{$I$}$$
Use $\displaystyle \int_0^a f(x) dx=\int_0^a f(a-x) dx$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan(\pi/2-x))}+\frac{1}{1-\tan(\pi/2-x)}\right)dx$$
Use $\displaystyle \tan(\pi/2-x)=\cot(x)$
$$
I=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\cot(x))}+\frac{1}{1-\cot(x)}\right)dx\tag{$II$}$$
Add $(I)$ and $(II)$
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan(x))}+\frac{1}{1-\tan(x)}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\cot(x))}+\frac{1}{1-\cot(x)}\right)dx$$
Simplify using $\displaystyle \log(\cot x)=\log(1/\tan x)=-\log(\tan x)$
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\cot(x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan x}\right)dx$$
Use $\displaystyle \cot x\tan x=1$ after taking common denominators to get:
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}dx=\frac{\pi}2$$
Just the final step:
$$I=\frac{\pi}4\Box$$

Comment: You seem to have confused $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in places.

Comment: @Travis edited /.

Comment: The upper bound of the integral is $\frac{\pi}{4}$, @Aditya.

Comment: The limits on the original integral were $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$. (NB that the (improper) integral of the first term over $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ is just zero.)

Comment: @Travis Well the first term alone, the integral is not defined, in the same way that $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{x}$ is undefined, but can be given a principal value of $0$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value The same for the second term. The advantage of the sum is that their infinite components cancel.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, please see my clarifying edit.

Comment: @Travis you shouldn't have edited, rather made a new comment

Comment: That's not an "improper integral." That's something else. This is a Cauchy principal value, not an improper integral. @Travis

Comment: @travis on second thought see the value: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D+%28+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Clog+%28%5Ctan+x%29%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1-%5Ctan+x%7D+%29dx) which is $.785398$ in close agreement with $\pi/4=.785398163$

Comment: Aditya, you apparently evaluated the original integrand over a different interval than that used in question.

Comment: @Travis I'm aware, and am waiting for OP's clarification

Comment: You're right, @ThomasAndrews, I'd temporarily confused the two intervals myself.

Comment: I believe that it probably _is_ $\dfrac\pi4$, not $\dfrac\pi2$. In which case, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/913469/166353) is the correct one. Olivier gets $\displaystyle\frac\pi8+\frac74\ln2+\frac\gamma2+\ln\pi-2\ln \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$ as the answer.

Comment: @Aditya The upper limit is exactly $\dfrac\pi4$. Thank you. (+1)