# Evaluating $\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan(x)}\right)^3dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form, polygamma

Using [the method shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913195/integral-int-0-large-frac-pi4-left-frac1-log-tanx-frac11/913469#913469), I have found the following closed form.

> $$
> \int_0^{\!\Large \frac{\pi}{2}}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan x}\right)^2\! \mathrm dx= 3\ln2-\frac{4}{\pi}G -\frac12, 
> $$

where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

I can see that replicating the techniques for the following integral could be rather lenghty.

> $$
> \int_0^{\!\Large \frac{\pi}{2}}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan x}\right)^3\! \mathrm dx 
> $$

**My question:** Could someone have, ideally, a different idea to evaluate the latter integral?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found it.

We have

> $$
> \int_0^{\!\Large \frac{\pi}{2}}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan x}\right)^3\! \mathrm dx= \color{blue}{\frac92\ln2-\frac{6}{\pi}G -\frac34 -\frac\pi8} \tag1 
> $$

where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

*Proof.* Set
$$
I_n:=\int_0^{\!\Large \frac{\pi}{2}}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan x}\right)^n\! \mathrm dx, \, n=0,1,2... . \tag2
$$
Clearly
$$
I_0=\frac\pi2.
$$
Recall that
$$
\tan \!\left(\!\frac\pi2 -x\!\right) =  \frac{1}{\tan x}
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\log \tan \!\left(\!\frac\pi2 -x\!\right) }+\frac{1}{1-\tan \!\left(\!\frac\pi2 -x\!\right)}& =\frac{1}{\log \left( \dfrac{1}{\tan x}\right) }+\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{\tan x}} \\\\
& =-\frac{1}{\log \left( \tan x \right) }-\frac{1}{1-\tan x}+1 \tag3
\end{align}
$$

Hence, by the change of variable $\displaystyle x \rightarrow \frac\pi2 -x$, we readily have
$$
\begin{align}
I_1&=\int_0^{\!\Large \frac{\pi}{2}}\!\!\left(-\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}-\frac{1}{1-\tan x}+1\right)\! \mathrm dx =-I_1+\frac\pi2 \tag4
\end{align}
$$
$$
I_1=\frac\pi4 .
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\!\Large \frac{\pi}{2}}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}+\frac{1}{1-\tan x}\right)^3\! \mathrm dx & =\int_0^{\!\Large \frac{\pi}{2}}\!\!\left(\!-\frac{1}{\log \left( \tan x\! \right) }-\frac{1}{1-\tan x}+1 \! \right)^3\! \mathrm dx
\end{align} \tag5 
$$
and, by the binomial expansion,
$$
\begin{align}
I_3 & =-I_3+3I_2-3I_1+I_0
\end{align}
$$
$$
I_3 =-I_3+3I_2-3\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac\pi2
$$
$$
I_3 =\frac32 I_2- \frac{\pi}{8} \tag6
$$
we may conclude with [this value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922342/evaluating-int-0-large-frac-pi2-left-frac1-log-tan-x-frac11) obtained for $I_2$.

A numerical approximation is
$$
\color{blue}{I_3=0.22709780663611705673940738484148718263....}
$$